# Unable to use apt-get or cpan

Tags: 12.10, apt, proxy, squid

I am using Ubuntu 12.10. A few days back I needed to change my proxy for connecting to the internet at my institute. After that I can't access the internet through terminal like can't install CPAN lib for Perl or install using `apt-get`. 
I changed my proxy to http host `172.0.16.200` and port `3128`. 
while I was back I used No Proxy using Firefox>Preferences>Advanced>Network>Settings
and also from Network>NetworkProxy>None

but while I try to install something I get message to authenticate for proxy server. It asks me for user name and password.

```
debasish@debasish:~$ sudo cpan App::cpanminus
[sudo] password for debasish: 

Fetching with HTTP::Tiny:
.................................../01mailrc.txt.gz
HTTP::Tiny failed with an internal error: Could not connect to '172.16.0.200:3128': IO::Socket::INET: connect: timeout at /usr/share/perl/5.14/HTTP/Tiny.pm line 139


Proxy authentication needed!
 (Note: to permanently configure username and password run
   o conf proxy_user your_username
   o conf proxy_pass your_password
     )
Username:  debasish.mukherjee

Trying with
    /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/debasish/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz.tmp4734"
to get
    .......................................01mailrc.txt.gz
--2012-12-18 01:06:16--  http://cpan.repo.unpas.ac.id/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Connecting to 172.16.0.200:3128...  failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2012-12-18 01:07:20--  (try: 2) ......
```

and it ultimately fails.

I also can't install from "Ubuntu Software Centre" or update my os as it showing "Requires installation of untrusted packages"

Please help.

Comment: Try setting proxy to "None" in Network and click "Apply system wide"

Comment: I have already done that.. it is of no use

Comment: What is the output of `echo $http_proxy`?

Answer (score 0):

A proxy is set using a global variable, but not all software uses this value. Sometimes this needs to be configured per application.
Read up on the most used applications [here](http://www.phulstaert.be/?p=21).

CPAN/PEAR/PECL:

```
pear config-set http_proxy http://username:password@your.proxy:8080
```

APT-GET:

```
echo 'Acquire::http::proxy "http://username:password@your.proxy:8080";' >> /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

Comment: `$ export http_proxy=''` can clear up the proxy settings too. you can set the proxy to none using `$ unity-control-center network`